# .Net SDK is not found in VSCode

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code

I installed the SDK 5.0 for windows (just like in this video https://youtu.be/a6WPeTG1QEk) and it is actually present under C:\Programs Files\dotnet, but when I type dotnet new consol -o myApp in cmd it gives me the following error:

```
> PS D:\Programme\VSCodeNetCoreTest> dotnet new console
Could not execute because the application was not found or a compatible .NET SDK is not installed.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You intended to execute a .NET program:
      The application 'new' does not exist.
  * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
      It was not possible to find any installed .NET SDKs.
      Install a .NET SDK from:
        https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

(This is in VSCode and has no -o myApp but it gives me the same error in cmd)
I have added the dotnet directory to PATH and it still wont run.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does it return: dotnet --list-sdks

Comment: Nothing... just a blank line, but dotnet --info says I have no SDKs installed which is false

Comment: C:\Programs Files\dotnet does that path have sdk directory?

Comment: Yes it has the 5.0.202 SDK Directory in it

Comment: Try to add it to PATH as well

Comment: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.202 is the Path I added and it still does not work

Comment: Hmm. I have only C:\Program Files\dotnet\ as PATH

Comment: That was the first Path I added but it didn't work

Comment: Weird. Try to install .net core 3.1 and see what happens. After installing it make sure you have C:\Program Files\dotnet\ in your path variable

Comment: Sadly it does not... it still gives me the same error

Comment: Last advice I can give is try to install visual studio. No way it can be installed without sdk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am trying to create a dotnet console application in Visual Studio Code and getting the same error. Below are my findings & the solution that worked for me:

**Problem:** In VS code, c# files are not executing or unable to create dotnet console application from terminal.

**Error:** Could not execute because the application is not found or a compatible .Net SDk is not installed

*I already have installed .Net SDK on my machine.*

---

**How to diagnose:**
In cmd, run command: **dotnet --version**
-> Could not execute because the application is not found or a compatible .Net SDk is not installed...blablabla

run command: **where dotnet**
-> C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe

---

**Root Cause**: There are two exe files i.e. dotnet.exe present in c drive at different locations i.e.:
C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet
C:\Program Files\dotnet

And in system environment variables - Path - both are added (x86) one being at first.
As I am using 64 bit OS, I am supposed to use the later path for dotnet.exe.

---

**Solution**: Go to "Environment Variables" dialog from start menu, edit the system environment variable "Path"-

1. Either swap both the paths of dotnet in System environment variable Path
2. Or simply delete the unwanted path(in my case: C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet)
   and Save.

---

**Check**: Reopen cmd in admin mode & run command - **dotnet --version**
-> 6.0.101

Reopen visual studio code & in terminal, open the folder where you want to place your c# console application, run command - **dotnet new console**
-> obj, csproj, program.cs are now added in the folder. Add a simple C# code to Print "Hello World" in Program.cs & run.

Comment: Where do I find environment variables?

Answer (score 3):

The exact details are discussed here: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/14916

TL:DR There were two dotnet.exe files in Program Files and Program Files(x86), that I had to delete both and reinstall via Visual Studio 2019 (porably not the only method).

Now there is only one dotnet.exe in Program Files and it finally works.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue while creating Function apps in VS Code. I did the following:

1. File -> Preferences -> Settings
2. I searched for Functions -> Azure Functions ->Azure Functions: Project Runtime
3. Select the desired Runtime and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue, could not build using dotnet in vscode or local build agent but I could build using visual studio.

When running "dotnet build -v diag" in bash I found that there is an Environment Variable "MSBuildSDKsPath" that was set to a non existing version.

I tried changing it to a different version which did not work. In the end I just deleted it and that fixed my build.