# VScode/Visual Studio not showing red squiggles in the text editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got a new laptop recently. I use vscode to do c# scripts for unity projects for college. I installed unity and then got both visual studio and vscode. Couldn't get the red squiggles to appear under any errors. I have no idea why. When I search for red squiggles in settings I don't have that option. I'm very frustrated. Any help would be appreciated.[Here is a screenshot of an obvious error that isn't showing as an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMfTm.png)

Comment: I am not sure but, did you have Microsoft Visual Studio IDE and not Visual Studio Code before. You seem to have just opened a file alone and not a Project. Does this do the "red squiggles" when opening alone files?

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine Yeah I had Visual studio before I downloaded vsCode. I'm not sure what you mean by opening a file alone? I just double clicked my script in unity and it opened vscode but with no red squiggles.

Comment: Visual studio code is closer to an editor, not like Visual studio that has much more functionalities. However, i guess, but i am not sure at all, you just opened this file in vscode like you open a text editor except it knows it is C#. Maybe the syntax/logic is only checked when you open the file in a project (by this I mean that you would be able to compile and run it), it would require the system environment the code is supposed to execute on, etc ...

Answer (score 1):

Did you download unity extensions for vscode, I personnally use :

-Unity Code Snippets

-Unity Tools

-Debugger for Unity

Comment: Yes I have them but it doesn't change anything. I'm after getting a warning saying The .NET Core SDK cannot be located. .NET Core debugging will not be enabled. Make sure the .NET Core SDK is installed and is on the path. I'm pretty sure its on the right path. I'm very confused

Comment: I found this and I think it might help you try these solutions:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60712895/the-net-core-sdk-cannot-be-located-net-core-debugging-will-not-be-enabled-ma