# Why my Visual Studio Code's Microsoft C# extension always display dotnet not found?

Tags: c#, .net

I downloaded this C# extension from Visual Studio Code Extension Store and dotnet as well.But, the extension cannot detect my dotnet core SDK.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L100t.png)
(I want to learn C# language,but the problem has been haunting me for days)

> The .NET Core SDK cannot be located: A valid dotnet installation could not be found. .NET Core debugging will not be enabled. Make sure the .NET Core SDK is installed and is on the path.

> Cannot create .NET debug configurations. The active C# project is not within folder 'c:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\Desktop\project\idk'.

I have downloaded dotnet several times and I also checked the version of visual studio code, it is v1.80.Dotnet Core SDK i downloaded is .NET7.0 SDK (v7.0.305) .
I closed my visual studio code and download dotnet again and then restart visual studio code again,I saw this method at [The .NET Core SDK cannot be located. .NET Core debugging will not be enabled. Make sure the .NET Core SDK is installed and is on the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60712895/the-net-core-sdk-cannot-be-located-net-core-debugging-will-not-be-enabled-ma), but it doesn't work.

Pls help me to solve this issue. Thank you very much

Comment: Open a command prompt (or use VSCode terminal) and run `dotnet --list-sdks` and `dotnet --list-runtimes` to see if they are in your PATH. Also try to not use OneDrive to store your code, it may be intefering with/blocking some files. Put your code in C:\code or something for now.